# SELECT em múltiplas tabelas SQLITE

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tenho uma tabela de clientes e faço uma listagem de todos os itens desta tabela em `SQLite`
Preciso além de listar estes clientes, buscar também a menor data, referente ao cliente, em outra tabela.

Exemplo:

```
**Tabela de Clientes**
id | codigo_cliente | nome_cliente
 1 |     0001       |     Joao
 2 |     0002       |     Maria
 3 |     0003       |     Carlos
 4 |     0004       |     Jose
 5 |     0005       |     Antonio
 6 |     0006       |     Oscar

**Tabela de Visitas**
id | codigo_cliente | data_visita
 1 |      0001      | 01/05/2017
 2 |      0001      | 03/06/2017
 3 |      0001      | 22/10/2017
 4 |      0002      | 15/05/2017
 5 |      0002      | 20/02/2017
 6 |      0004      | 04/03/2017
 7 |      0004      | 18/10/2017
 8 |      0004      | 13/05/2017
 9 |      0004      | 01/02/2017
10 |      0006      | 03/06/2017
11 |      0006      | 18/02/2017
```

Neste caso preciso listar os clientes e que junto venha a menor data de visita da Tabela de Visitas:

```
**Lista de Clientes**
id | codigo_cliente  | nome_cliente | data_vista
1 |      0001       |     Joao     | 01/05/2017
2 |      0002       |     Maria    | 20/02/2017
3 |      0003       |     Carlos   |
4 |      0004       |     Jose     | 18/02/2017
5 |      0005       |     Antonio  |
```

Por favor, como seria este SELECT em SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

É só fazer um `GROUP BY` e `MIN()`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.codigo_cliente, c.nome_cliente, MIN(v.data_visita) AS data_visita
  FROM CLIENTES c
 INNER JOIN VISITAS v ON c.codigo_cliente = v.codigo_cliente
 GROUP BY c.id, c.codigo_cliente, c.nome_cliente
;
```

Note que o `GROUP BY` tem que ser por **todas** as colunas que não vão receber uma função agregadora (neste caso, `MIN()`). Fora isso, é um SQL bastante simples.

Comment: Muito obrigado Wtrmute, funcionou.  Porém esqueci de mencionar que eventualmente pode acontecer de alguns clientes não terem registro na tabela VISITAS.  Assim, preciso listar este cliente mesmo que não haja registro na tabela VISITAS.

Comment: só alterar para 'INNER JOIN VISITAS v ON c.codigo_cliente = v.codigo_cliente OR c.codigo_cliente IS NOT NULL', não tenho como testar no momento, mas vale a tentativa

Comment: Obrigado Mathias, testei aqui e netse caso ele retorna a mesma data para todos os clientes, até os clientes que não tem data.

Comment: Preciso neste caso, se não houver data relacionada a este cliente na  tabela VISITAS, que o cliente apareça na lista com a data vazia mesma.

Comment: Nesse caso, é como eu escrevi, mas `LEFT JOIN` ou `LEFT OUTER JOIN` no lugar de `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Funcionou esta ultima opção Wtrmute, utilizando `LEFT JOIN`.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda.